# issue when creating IPA file

Tags: ipa, trigger.io

I'm seeing this error:

```
[  ERROR] Something went wrong that we didn't expect:
[  ERROR] Failed when running /usr/bin/codesign: iPhone Developer: no identity found

[  ERROR] See /Users/yuanfengfeng/Desktop/Chrome_Download/test/forge-error.log for more details
[  ERROR] Please contact support@trigger.io
```

Please give me some clues on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: From our interaction on support email, I think you have now resolved this by creating a new certificate since you'd originally created the one you were trying to use on a different computer. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you haven't got a iPhone Developer certificate in your keychain or are trying to reference it incorrectly with the 'forge package' command.

Send the exact command you're running and the forge-error.log file to support@trigger.io and we'll help you resolve it.

Our documentation for releasing on iOS and Android is here: https://trigger.io/docs/current/recipes/release/release_mobile.html